Refresh global environment variables in vscode with remote-ssh after modifying .bashrc
I'm recently using vscode installed on Windows 11 to connect to a CentOS 7 server with remote-ssh. I put all my environmental variable settings at $HOME/.bashrc on the server, and I need to change them frequently to see the correspondingly effects.
Many people say that vscode initialize the environment variables by invoking a login terminal, and inherit them to all non-login terminals invoked subsequently. To my understanding, this means that .bashrc will be sourced only after I invoked a shell manually, thus the environment variables defined .bashrc won't be inherited. However this is not true for me: Even if I deleted .bash_profile and .profile, environment variables in .bashrc will be sourced and inherited, and every terminal I invoke manually has duplicated entries in $PATH. Environment variables cannot be reinitialized simply by opening a new terminal.
I'm aware that using "Kill Current VS Code server" after modifying .bashrc is feasible to reinitialize environment variables. It is, though, very annoying since I have to enter my password and OTP code twice each time (key login disabled by admin). I have also set both "Terminal › Integrated: Inherit Env" and "Terminal › Integrated › Shell Integration: Enabled" to False, but neither of them work.
Is there any method to refresh environment variables without killing the remote server? Or maybe I missed some settings?
Regards.

I'm facing the same problem but it's worse for me. The "Kill Current VS Code server" command for some reason doesn't help, so I have to rm -rf .vscode-server to reload the environment after ~/.bashrc changes. It is very annoying because afterwards I need to reinstall the extensions which I had :-(
